# Windows 10 IoT Core physical keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, uwp, windows-iot-core

We are trying to use several RaspberryPi 3 as clients with headed UWP applications. We are using physical keyboards but can't figure out how to set the keyboard layout. How would one go about doing this?